# regex assistance - 1 case I need to handle yet

Tags: regex

This is kind of doing what I want, but is failing one case I'd like to be true.  Yes, I will be using this with domains, but before someone goes on and on about how this won't work for whatever domain, there is more needed to validate it correctly, and so on... this WILL work fine in my use case if I can handle these two last cases.  I do not need to validate correct format, just need to make sure it handles the cases I mention below.  Basically I am looking for :

- any *.extension (a-z more than 2 chars) to be true
- any domain.extension or unlimited-subdomains.domain.extension to be true
- either of the above where the entire string starts with *. to be true

What I have gotten so far :

[regex101.com of my current regex](https://regex101.com/r/kii30q/1)

```
/^(?:\*\.)?([a-z0-9-]{1,255}\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i
```

- `(?:\*\.)?` - can optionally start with *.
- `([a-z0-9-]{1,255}\.)*` - 0 or more of a-z0-9- between 1-255 ending with .
- `[a-z]{2,}` ends with a-z between 2-?

Examples of what I want to true/false :

- `test` - false
- `.test` - false
- `*.test` - true
- `test.test` - true
- `*.test.test` - true

The current fails on `*.test` - which I would like to be true.

**EDIT:**

This 'works', but introduces a new test that is wrong.  `*.*.test` should be false.

[new regex](https://regex101.com/r/jesg41/1)

```
/^((?:\*\.)?([a-z0-9-]{1,255}\.)+[a-z]{2,})|\*.[a-z]{2,}$/i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(\*\.|([a-z0-9-]{1,255}\.))([a-z0-9-]{1,255}\.)*[a-z]{2,}$/i
```

**Explanation**:

`^` - match from start of string

`(` - create a group

`\*\.` - match `EITHER` a star `*` and a dot `.`

`|` - `OR`

`([a-z0-9-]{1,255}\.)` - match first part ending with a dot `.`

`)` - end group

`([a-z0-9-]{1,255}\.)*` - match repeated parts ending with a dot `.`

`[a-z]{2,}$` - match the final part and end of string

Note that the middle part is optional and can be repeated.

Comment: This seems to be it!  Looking how you did it that makes perfect sense.  I was going about it wrong.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much more simpler approach that satisfies your requirements and is more readable:

```
^(?:\*|[a-z0-9-]{1,255})(\.[a-z]{2,})+$
```

[image]

Comment: 'w' allows '_' which I do not want to allow, I do want to allow '-', and there should be a 255 limit on possible repeated part.

Comment: you can modify the regex to suit your requirements. all I wanted to say is: there is a more simpler way of achieving what you need to do.

Comment: After modifying it you would have the accepted answer though :)

Comment: @user756659 have a look at the updated answer.